# Running job on Bamboo "Not privileged to remove service." on osx

Tags: macos, service, bamboo, access-rights

When I run script:

```
launchctl remove com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

in terminal on build machine it is working allright, but when I run it from bamboo it fails and in log I see "Not privileged to remove service.". I have try to echo user id and it is same in terminal and in bamboo log. I do not understand why this is happening. Please, do you have any idea how to solve it? It does not work with sudo too.

Answer (score 1):

In accordance with the answer from *Bruce Tu*:

> Your Bamboo-Agent is running as a **launchDaemon** and not as a **launchAgent**.

To solve this you must move the `com.atlassian.bamboo-agent.plist` file from `/Library/LaunchDaemons` to `/Library/LaunchAgents` and restart the server.

Then you can add this to your bamboo build script to solve the CoreSimulator issue:

```
killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService || true
launchctl remove com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService || true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Jenkins builds. My solution might also apply to Bamboo.
I resolved it by running the following in a shell script that runs before the build begins.

This assumes that you allow sudo without having to type a password.
If not, it may also work that you can chown -R the user:group that will do the killing/deleting.

Hope this helps.

```
    sudo chmod -R g-w $(xcode-select -p)/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService.xpc 
    sudo chown -R root:wheel $(xcode-select -p)/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService.xpc 
    sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService || true
    sudo launchctl remove com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService || true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Bamboo on a Mac trying to run the command

```
launchctl remove com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

The problem was that I had Bamboo set up as a LaunchDaemon and not a LaunchAgent.  A LaunchAgent isn't able to access things like the iOS simulator, provisioning profiles, has permissions issues etc.  After I stopped the LaunchDaemon service and set Bamboo up as a LaunchAgent, I was able to run the command.

For more info on LaunchDaemon vs LaunchAgent see:
http://mgrebenets.github.io/mobile%20ci/2015/02/01/mobile-ci-daemon-vs-agent

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error while trying to launch a LaunchAgent in root context using `sudo -u"USER" launchctl remove <service>`.

The issue here was `sudo -u` won't work in all cases (eg: when it is used in postinstall script of packages).

Solution:

use combination of `sudo -u` and `launchctl asuser <userId>`

```
launchctl asuser <uid> sudo -u <uName> launchctl load -S Aqua -w "/Library/LaunchAgents/<plist>"
```

the combination is guaranteed to work.